# 2.4GHz antenna routing - my version vs reference board layout

Tags: pcb, antenna, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm working on a project with an nRF52840 on it. Due to space problems on the board I have to deviate from the setup recommended by Nordic, and I lack the experience to tell if I'm setting myself up to fail.

Version1:
This version is 99% identical to the board layout recommended by the datasheet. Note how F23 is connected to the pad under the chip which is GND. But also directly connected to the ground pad of first capacitor in the impedance matching network - at the expense of the actual antenna trace width. Even though a ground via is right next to it.

Version 2:
This is my take on the problem. I leave F23 be and use the space to route the antenna signal (H23) with the correct trace width.

Do you think version 2 will result in diminished antenna performance compared with the reference layout?

Version 1:
[image: Version 1]

Version 2:
[image: Version 2]

Answer (score 2):

Version 1 establishes a differential transmission line carrying RF and GND to the matching network.  Version 2 relies on the ground plane to provide a return path for the RF signal.  While I can't definitively say what effect that has on the coupling, it is fairly clear that the creators of version 1 went out of their way, at the very least compromising on trace width, to include the GND trace on their design in addition to the additional via to the ground plane.  I would treat any major variation to that layout as highly experimental and subject to detailed RF testing before incorporation into a product.  If you're not that concerned about range, it may be acceptable; OTOH, there's a remote possibility that it will work just as well.

Comment: The narrow trace width may even be an intentional feature to get the impedance right for its role in the matching network.

Answer (score 0):

In places like that, GND is just as much a signal as signal. Even if the ground plane route in version 2 is much wider than the trace in version 1, it's also a lot longer. If you ignore the recommended traces, then you are pretty much on your own with any re-tuning that needs to be done. I would not be surprised if the bond wires in the chip ran parallel and equal length to balls F23 and H23, expecting to find a differential line outside.

Who is to say you have used the 'correct' width of track in version 2? Both H23 and pin 1 of that first capacitor might have excess capacitance to ground, requiring a thinner track to match them.

In practice, with the narrow bandwidth, and the tuning components right there, you'll probably be able to tune your way out of any problem you cause by that small change of layout.